# HOw to send HTML form data to PHPmailer

Tags: php

Hopefully some one can help me here....

I am currently trying to correct issues with my contact form that is written in PHP. However I cannot seem to get it to work. I want to use PHP mailer and have it capture the form data but I cannot seem to find a post that shows me how.

How to use PHPmailer as the form processor?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't understand how to pass form variables to a php script, then please avoid using mail what so ever. We don't need more contributors to the never ending cycle of contact form spam.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help ?

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'namer@example.com';
$email->FromName  = 'John Doe';
$email->Subject   = 'SUBJECT HERE';

$contains_images = $_POST['mailcontent'];
$body  = '.$contains_images.';

$email->Body = $body;
$email->IsHTML(true); 

$email->AddAddress( 'some_recipient@gmail.com' );
return $email->Send();
```

HTML

```
<form id="blabla" action="processor.php" method="post" onsubmit="this.mailcontent.value = document.getElementById('selected-images').innerHTML;">
<input type="hidden" name="mailcontent" id="mailcontent" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="SEND EMAIL">
</form>
```